# Cant log in after lock screen by win+L

Tags: multiple-monitors, lock-screen

i have notebook and additional monitor. Sometimes, not each time(even not each day), i have problem: when i'm leaving my place i'm using win+L to lock screen. When i'm coming back i cant input login and password because there are no fields. They are just disappeared.

How can i catch it, notify ubuntu dev team and fix it ?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using, with what Ubuntu version - and could you add a photo of the issue please (you can use a link to https://imgur.com)

Comment: Does `CTRL`+`ALT`+`f1` give you a text mode login prompt? *(might be necessary to press `ENTER` at least once at times)*  If it does then `CTRL`+`ALT`+`f7` should bring the GUI back. By login via the text mode prompt you should be able to analyse what has happened. For starters try `dmsg | less`  +`ENTER`

Comment: @Wilf , 
`Linux b10s 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux `
and
`Unity`

What about photo is hard to do only by phone :) but i'll try next time.


@Hannu, yes, `CTRL+ALT+F1` gives me text mode and `CTRL+ALT+F7` brings me back without any help. I'll try to use dmsg | less next time, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well, and have found that pressing ESC and then moving my mouse fixes the problem.

It only seemed to start happening after I got an additional monitor.